# How to manipulate Euler's number in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

How should I do basic arithmetic including Euler's number in MATLAB? For example, what is Mat-ab expression to calculate E<sup>2</sup>?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `exp(1)` to get Euler's number in MATLAB. The [`exp(x)`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exp.html) function calculates *e*<sup>x</sup>.

Answer (score 3):

The Euler number is basicly the exponantial of 1

So

```
e = exp(1);
var = e^2;
```